# Why is my design screen gray and only says "androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout" in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to follow a playlist on YouTube by CodingInFlow for Android Studio development.

I'm trying to follow this video, but I'm having a problem...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-sPOtGqd5OA&list=PLrnPJCHvNZuBtcos16XJnfFx2fSUOyW_-&index=9

My design-screen is just showing as a gray box and I get the error that the "androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout (class couldn't be found)."

See code and example image here: [image: https://i.imgur.com/kub2gIH.png]

In the videos he's not using AndroidX and his opening-tag is different to mine in his .xml files.

His opening tag for his .xml document: **android.support.constraint**.ConstraintLayout

My opening tag for my .xml document: **androidx.constraintlayout**.ConstraintLayout

How can I fix this so that the design will show up where the gray box currently is?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have migrated to `androidx`

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

add this line to build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4"
}
```

in your xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is perhaps your are missing the library of it and it's not recognized.

Open your build.gradle (app) and add :

```
  implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

The video is a bit old regarding the "androidx" library, so that's why he's tag is different than yours. So you will have to add the library which supports it.